# How to change the content of datepicker-date-display in Materialize datepicker?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I wonder I can change the content of Materialze div class `datepicker-date-display`

[image: https://i.imgur.com/0P64qLG.png]

Format from options like `format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'` would be nice or even hiding the class might be better than what is there now.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/x7qa1w90/5/)

I am using Materialize 1.0

```
       var datepickerOptions ={
        
                  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                  autoClose : "true",
                  firstDay : 1,
        }  
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I read their doc, I didn't find a way to change the format of the date string that is displayed inside the picker. They expose an option called `format` that only works on output date string. So then, I wrote a workaround code. It's given below. You can also find the working code in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Showrin/smy78beq/14/ Thank you.

```
// HTML
<input class="datepicker" type=text value="2021-05-12"/>
<div id="datepicker-container"></div>
    

// JS
const dateToShow = '2021-05-08';

var datepickerOptions = {
  container: document.querySelector('#datepicker-container'),
  onOpen: function() {
    document.querySelector("#datepicker-container .datepicker-date-display").innerHTML = `<span class="date-text">${dateToShow}</span>`;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
});
```

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I wanted. I was thinking of the same but was also hoping for more native solution.

Comment: could you update your answer so it works for my jsfiddle sample. I got two date pickers.

Comment: I dont understand why this https://jsfiddle.net/radek/enfjvzcx/16/ works only for the first picker but the second one.

Comment: I created a question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456354/how-to-select-open-date-picker-queryselectordatepicker-container-open-date

Comment: Could you update your answer here, so I can accept it? Currently it does not answer my question correctly.

Comment: I replied there.