# How to select open date picker? querySelector("#datepicker-container .open .datepicker-date-display") does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have two Materialize datepickers used

```
<input class="datepicker" type=text value="2021-05-12"/>
<input class="datepicker" type=text value="2021-05-25"/>

<div id="datepicker-container"></div>
```

I want to update content of `.datepicker-date-display` so I thought that `document.querySelector("#datepicker-container .open .datepicker-date-display")` would work. But it does not return any element. `document.querySelector("#datepicker-container .datepicker-date-display")` - without .open returns always the first datepicker.

Any idea why addind `.open` to working querySelector does not work?

```
var datepickerOptions = {
  container: document.querySelector('#datepicker-container'),
  onOpen: function() {
  
    console.log(this.el.value)
    
    var e =  document.querySelector("#datepicker-container .datepicker-date-display")
console.log(e.className)    
    e.innerHTML = `<span class="date-text">${this.el.value}</span>`;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/enfjvzcx/24/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this one. Here's the link of js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Showrin/usp84k21/1/

```
onOpen: function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#datepicker-container .datepicker-date- 
display").forEach(container => {
    container.innerHTML = `<span class="date-text">${this.el.value}</span>`;
  })
}
```

Actually, querySelector grabs only the first element. That's why the second element was not changed. Use querySelectorAll. It'll solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution works but ... it changes the text of all datepickers even the ones that should not be changed. I guess it does not matter because they are not displayed.

Comment: Yes, it will change the text of all date pickers. Cause you are using the same options for all. If you don't want it, then use different containers with different IDs for each datepickers, and moderate the onOpen function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for a solution to my own question I thought that at the time onOpen callback is fired the datepicker is `not opened` yet. So I implemented solution that `waits` for the open class. I wonder if there is any `better` solution.  I like anwer from `Showrin Barua`

```
var datepickerOptions = {
  container: document.querySelector('#datepicker-container'),
  onOpen: function() {
    var location = "#datepicker-container .open .datepicker-date-display"
    var value = this.el.value
    setText(location,value)
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, datepickerOptions);
});


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function setText(location,value) {
  // Pause execution of this async function for 2 seconds
  await sleep(50);
  var e =  document.querySelector(location)
 
  if(e == null){
    setText(location,value)
  }else{
    e.innerHTML = `<span class="date-text">${value}</span>`;
  }
  //console.log(e.className)    
  //console.log('Waited for 2 seconds');
}
```

working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/enfjvzcx/52/)